# How to set focus on list view at 0 index

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set focus on list view when it is loaded. I have a requirement where I want to implement navigation on list view like when an up button is pressed I want it to move one step up and similar for down button. Till now I have tried almost most of the methods like 
**set selection(position),listview.requestfocus(), list.setSelected(true),list.setItemsCanFocus(true)** but nothing has worked so far.
I have also tried this method  to get the view inside the list view and it works fine :

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
then I am getting the view and trying to set focus..however it does not work                

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getViewByPosition(0, list);
                    View v = getViewByPosition(0, list);

                    Log.v("WifiScanReceiver", "View found: " + v);
                    v.setFocusable(true);
                    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    v.requestFocus();


                }
            });
```

Any suggestions to achieve the focus would be appreciated.I have researched a lot and nothing has worked so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 
                                         "Android Example List View" 
                                        };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);



        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        listView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelection(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think what you want is the "setSelection" method instead of focus if I understand your question correctly. Have a look at this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: @kha: I tried this but it doesnot make any difference to the list like I want the list's first index to be focused  by default..setselection did not work in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may or may not have visual effect (background highlighting) depending on some devices. So, Set some focus color to that view

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(focusedPosition);
        View v = getViewByPosition(0, list);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this "setselection" method supposed to kinda highlight index 0

Comment: because for the time being it is not making any difference to the listview...I need to make the index 0 focused

Comment: Is it not going to first position using this setSelection method??

Comment: @useruser543: No its Not Moreover I have just edited the code and added a sample listview code and used it there but nothing worked.. if you could check that at your end as well would be a great help

Comment: In ur view foucused means what.. Do u want to highlight that position??

Answer (score 3):

Hello all thank you so much for great responses and they all were very helpfull. However the exact thing that worked is:

```
list.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        list.getChildAt(indexPos + 1).setBackgroundColor(
                                Color.RED);
                        list.getChildAt(indexPos).setBackgroundColor(
                                Color.BLACK);
                        // String selectedFromList = (String) (list
                        // .getItemAtPosition(0));
                        Log.v("Case2", "Selected text is:" + selectedFromList);
                    }
```

Where I have list background as red and for the selected index I am changing the background to black.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.text1, values) {

        public View getView(int pos, View convertView,
                android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            }
            TextView tv =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(values[pos]));
            if (pos == 0) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            return v;

        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

A) The documentation says it's safe to touch your views only after the `onResume` method's been called.

B) I had the same issue...my solution was pretty easy :D

```
@Override 
protected void Resume() {
    //do whatever you need here
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.requestFocus();
            },500);//the delay period can be changed, of course

}
```